# Let $X$ be the wedge $\Bbb S^1 \vee \Bbb S^1$. Show that $X$ doesn't have the fixed point property.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be the figure eight of two circles of radius $1$ centered at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$. That is $X$ is the wedge $\Bbb S^1 \vee \Bbb S^1$. Show that $X$ doesn't have the fixed point property.

This has answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167967/does-the-union-of-two-circles-have-the-fixed-point-property) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243588/the-wedge-sum-of-two-circles-has-fixed-point-property?rq=1) but neither one of them explicitly defines the rotation map. So if we have $f : X \to X$ sending $(x,y) \mapsto (-x,y)$ i.e. the right cirlce to the left one. How do we define $g$ as the rotation map? Do we use the rotation matrix in some way?

Comment: What is the relevance of the rotation map to the question?

Comment: What do you mean by relevance? In order to define the composition of these two maps I sure would need to know the other map I'm composing with. @IgorRivin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you have to keep in mind that you are rotating not around the origin, but around the center $(-1,0)$ of the left circle.

This rotation can be expressed in terms of the usual rotation as follows: rotation around the origin by $\pi/2$ radians is given by the map $r(x,y) = (-y,x)$. In order to rotate around $(-1,0)$, we move this point to the origin, rotate, and then move back, so we end up with the map
$$
r'(x,y) = r(x+1,y) - (1,0) = (-y,x+1) - (1,0) = (-y-1,x+1).
$$

Your final map $\Phi: \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{S}^1 \vee \mathbb{S}^1$ is then described as
$$
\Phi(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
r'(x,y), & \text{if } x \leq 0, \\
r'(f(x,y)), & \text{if } x \geq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The continuous map $f:X\to X$ without fixed point proposed by Conifold in the first comment of [your first link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3167967) is :

> *First reflect the second circle onto the first about the vertical, then rotate the image 90 degrees counterclockwise.*

(Speaking of two circles of radius 1, centered at $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.)

So $f=g\circ h$, where:

- $h$ acts as $(x,y)\mapsto(-x,y)$ on the second circle, but as $\rm{id}$ on the first one
- $g$ is in fact *any* "true" rotation (i.e. with non-zero angle) with center $(-1,0).$